# how to access values in a dictionary in python without knowing the actual values?

Tags: python

I am a python rookie and so my question is simple (yet I couldn't find the answer here):

I need to access values in my dictionary (named 'database') but without knowing the actual values. So lets say I want to print the first value of the dictionary whatever it is. I found this:

```
print(database.values()[0].keys()[0])
```

Which seems to be what I'm looking for but when running the script I get this error:

> TypeError: 'database' object does not support indexing

Can you please help?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first value" because dictionaries are unordered.  You can get the first thing in `values` but there's no guarantee it will be the first later.  Anyway, if you want to do that, why are you involving `keys()` at all?  Just do `database.values()[0]`.

Comment: I have given sample code below that works. Check it out

Comment: I guess I didnt explain it very well. So, I have a dictionary called database that stores student IDs as key and student names as values. I want the user to input grades for each student for a number of exams (the number of exams is same for all students). And the output should look like this: {'1234': {'Name': 'Josh', 'Scores': [88,99,77]}}.

 So I need to loop through the dictionary and change {'1234': Josh} to {'1234': {'Name': 'Josh', 'Scores': [88,99,77]}} but I dont know why.

Comment: This question you asked now is very far from the title and the description you have given. You may want to open a new thread by asking the question separately with proper description.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Ordered Dict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/#ordered-dict-api):

As others mentioned in the comments, you would get the elements in no particular order because dictionaries are unordered.

This sample code works:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

database = OrderedDict()
database = {
          "key1": {"key10": "value10", "key11": "value11"},
          "key2": {"key20": "value20", "key21": "value21"}
          }
```

If you want to print out or access all first dictionary keys in database.values() list, you may use something like this:

```
for key, value in database.items():
    print value.keys()[0]
```

If you want to just access first key of the first item in database.values(), this may be useful:

```
print database.values()[0].keys()[0]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but that isnt it exactly the same as I wrote (the last line of code)?

Anyway, I guess I didnt explain it very well. So,

I have a dictionary called database that stores student IDs as key and student names as values. I want the user to input grades for each student for a number of exams (the number of exams is same for all students). And the output should look like this: {'1234': {'Name': 'Josh', 'Scores': [88,99,77]}}.

But I dont know how to assign each student list of his grades so it looks like Im suggesting above.